# Error comparing dates in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, casting

Within a ASP.NET/C# class I am trying to run a query where I compare dates:

```
select * from table1 CreatedDate >='DATEADD(d,-500,GETDATE())';
```

Basically I am trying to select rows from the the last 500 days.

The problem is I am getting the following error:
Syntax error converting datetime from character string.

An example of the CreatedDate field in the database is `2003-09-19 15:32:23.283` . The field is set to type = datetime, default = getdate().

If I run the query `SELECT DATEADD(d,-500,GETDATE())`; it returns 2008-09-17 23:41:34.710

The 2 values look the same so I am surprised am getting the error message. An idea on how I need to modify my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table1 CreatedDate >= DATEADD(d,-500,GETDATE())
```

Lose the quotes around `DATEADD(d,-500,GETDATE())`. These make the expression varchar

[Datatype precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) means you are trying to convert a string starting DATEADD to datetime...

Comment: Doh! That was an easy fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried without the single quotes?

```
CreatedDate >=DATEADD(d,-500,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put apostrophes around the dateadd expression, so it's not an expression, it's a string. That's the string that it fails to convert to a datetime value.

```
select * from table1 CreatedDate >= DATEADD(d,-500,GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove '' quotes